# pprint dictionary on multiple lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pprint

I'm trying to get a pretty print of a dictionary, but I'm having no luck:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> a = {'first': 123, 'second': 456, 'third': {1:1, 2:2}}
>>> pprint.pprint(a)
{'first': 123, 'second': 456, 'third': {1: 1, 2: 2}}
```

I wanted the output to be on multiple lines, something like this:

```
{'first': 123,
 'second': 456,
 'third': {1: 1,
           2: 2}
}
```

Can [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) do this? If not, then which module does it? I'm using [Python 2.7.3](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pretty print nested dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229419/how-to-pretty-print-nested-dictionaries)

Comment: @Georgy not quite. The desired output in that question is not the same as mine is here

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Use `width=1` or `width=-1`:

```
In [33]: pprint.pprint(a, width=1)
{'first': 123,
 'second': 456,
 'third': {1: 1,
           2: 2}}
```

Comment: What do negative widths do?

Comment: @Tim:  I just tried it, and it worked, but I don't know if that is documented somewhere.

Comment: Negative widths don't do anything special. As the code goes along, it checks to see if the length of the partial output string is `< width`.  Any negative width just means the answer will always be "no". A width of 0 will almost always (or maybe always - I don't care enough to think about perverse cases ;-)) do the same.

Comment: @TimPeters:  Yeah, I took a look at the source.  There is a check for width==0 (it raises an error), but it seems that 0 could be treated the same as a negative value--always answer "no", as you put it--with no harm.

Answer (score 56):

You could convert the dict to json through `json.dumps(d, indent=4)`

```
import json

print(json.dumps(item, indent=4))
{
    "second": 456,
    "third": {
        "1": 1,
        "2": 2
    },
    "first": 123
}
```

Comment: Much prettier than the other solutions

Comment: @ErikAronesty While you should pay attention to the `null` and boolean values (true/false). They are JSON values not the python objects.

Comment: Okay solution for simple cases, but converts python values to json values (as @RyanChou pointed out) and it might not be desirable or possible (like with `datetime`): `json.dumps({'d': datetime.now()})` will crash with `Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable`.

Comment: `NameError: name 'json' is not defined` - Is this a module that needs importing? If so, would you mind updating your answer to reflect that?

Answer (score 28):

If you are trying to pretty print the environment variables, use:

```
pprint.pprint(dict(os.environ), width=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Two things to add on top of Ryan Chou's already very helpful answer:

- pass the `sort_keys` argument for an easier visual grok on your dict, esp. if you're working with pre-3.6 Python (in which dictionaries are unordered)

```py
print(json.dumps(item, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
"""
{
    "first": 123,
    "second": 456,
    "third": {
        "1": 1,
        "2": 2
    }
}
"""
```

- `dumps()` will only work if the dictionary keys are primitives (strings, int, etc.)

Comment: Neat! `sort_keys` is a great argument. Unfortunately, as you say not always applicable: `TypeError: Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable`...

Answer (score -1):

This is a Copy-Pasta for testing purposes and to help with a usage example.

```py
from pprint import pprint  # I usually only need this module from the package. 

a = {'first': 123, 'second': 456, 'third': {1:1, 2:2}, 'zfourth': [{3:9, 7:8}, 'distribution'], 1:2344, 2:359832, 3:49738428, 4:'fourth', 5:{'dictionary':'of things', 'new':['l','i','s','t']}}

pprint(dict(a), indent=4, width=1)

# Wrap your variable in dict() function
# Optional: indent=4. for readability
# Required: width=1 for wrapping each item to its own row.
# Note: Default pprint is to sort the dictionary
# Note: This also auto-wraps anything sting that has spaces in it.  See 'of things' below.

# Documentation:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html
# Examples:       https://pymotw.com/2/pprint/
# Blog:           https://realpython.com/python-pretty-print/
```

Provides the following result:

```py
{   1: 2344,
    2: 359832,
    3: 49738428,
    4: 'fourth',
    5: {   'dictionary': 'of '
                         'things',
           'new': [   'l',
                      'i',
                      's',
                      't']},
    'first': 123,
    'second': 456,
    'third': {   1: 1,
                 2: 2},
    'zfourth': [   {   3: 9,
                       7: 8},
                   'distribution']}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is intended to a) answer the question; b) add any information that isn't thoroughly covered by existing answers.

Comment: This helps as it is just a different perspective with a copy paste option.  As sometimes snippets do not exactly convey the point to new learners.