# formatting dictionary printing output

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary called `d` which has several lists stored into it. If I print the dictionary I get this difficult to read output :

```
 {'Patch(0,8)': [28, 56, 75], 'Patch(0,6)': [1, 11, 17, 19, 20, 23, 28, 30, 44, 45, 49, 56, 60, 63, 75, 81, 91, 99], 
 'Patch(4,0)': [2, 5, 6, 8, 19, 22, 23, 27, 31, 34, 35, 36, 41, 45, 51, 52, 53, 55, 56, 59, 60, 61, 62, 64, 66, 67, 68, 70, 73, 75, 76, 77, 79, 85, 87, 91, 94, 96], 
 'Patch(4,6)': [19, 23, 45, 56, 60, 75, 91], 'Patch(0,0)': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 
  57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99], 'Patch(8,0)': [2, 22, 23, 27, 34, 52
 , 55, 60, 85], 'Patch(0,2)': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 32, 34, 36, 37, 38, 40, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,
  49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 56, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 66, 70, 71, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 83, 85, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 98, 99], 'Patch(2,8)': [28, 56, 75], 'Patch(4,8)': [56, 75]}
```

I just want to print each `Patch` and corresponding data in a new line :

```
 {'Patch(0,8)': [28, 56, 75], 
  'Patch(0,6)': [1, 11, 17, 19, 20, 23, 28, 30, 44, 45, 49, 56, 60, 63, 75, 81, 91, 99],
```

I tried `pprint` after seeing the suggestions in [this answer :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171392/python-pprint-dictionary-on-multiple-lines)

```
 pprint.pprint(d, width=1)
```

I get this :

```
  {'Patch(0,8)': [28, 
                 56, 
                 75], and so on
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pass in width that is big enough to hold every value in the `dict`:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(d, width=1000)
{'Patch(0,0)': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99],
 'Patch(0,2)': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 32, 34, 36, 37, 38, 40, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 56, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 66, 70, 71, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 83, 85, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 98, 99],
 'Patch(0,6)': [1, 11, 17, 19, 20, 23, 28, 30, 44, 45, 49, 56, 60, 63, 75, 81, 91, 99],
 'Patch(0,8)': [28, 56, 75],
 'Patch(2,8)': [28, 56, 75],
 'Patch(4,0)': [2, 5, 6, 8, 19, 22, 23, 27, 31, 34, 35, 36, 41, 45, 51, 52, 53, 55, 56, 59, 60, 61, 62, 64, 66, 67, 68, 70, 73, 75, 76, 77, 79, 85, 87, 91, 94, 96],
 'Patch(4,6)': [19, 23, 45, 56, 60, 75, 91],
 'Patch(4,8)': [56, 75],
 'Patch(8,0)': [2, 22, 23, 27, 34, 52, 55, 60, 85]}
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually print dicts as JSON to give it structure and formatting I can easily read.

```
import json
json.dumps( dict( a=1, b=2), indent=2)
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP wants, though: it puts the list items on separate lines. Using JSON to display dicts _can_ be handy, but it has various limitations: non-string keys get converted to strings; `None`, `True`, and `False` get converted to their JSON equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this into a simple loop to print it. have a look at [`dict.iteritems`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) for the official docs.

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    print key + " - " + str(value)
```

Comment: FWIW, in Python 3 `dict.iteritems` doesn't exist. Instead, `dict.items` now returns an iterator, so  you can use `dict.items` in code that has to run on both versions (of course in Python 2 it'll return a list instead of an iterator, so it'll probably use more RAM).