# How can I print dictionary value without newline '\n' character?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say this is my dictionary.

```
d = {"id": 12345, "msg": "Some msgs \n from the \n text file"}
```

I want to print this dictionary as:

```
>>> print(d)
{
"id": 12345,
"msg": "Some msgs
        from the
        text file"
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Also, I'm not able to return a string with newline characters into a formatted string.
Let's say below is my string:

```
str = "Some msgs \n from the \n text file"
```

On printing it, I'll get formatted string:

```
>>> print(str)
Some msgs
from the
text file
```

But how can I make below code work similarly to print formatted dictionary?

```
d["msg"] = str
print(d)
```

Comment: what is expected ?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani read the 2nd line "I want to print this dictionary as:"

Comment: As far as I know python automatically translates `\n` to the proper newline character.

Comment: In the second part of your problem, you mean inserting the string to the dictionary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pretty print nested dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229419/how-to-pretty-print-nested-dictionaries)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171392/pprint-dictionary-on-multiple-lines

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you would have to loop over the dictionary elements, and print them as keys and values

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print('"{0}": {1}'.format(k, v))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that I know your problem,
you can print it this way:
define a dictionary as `student_score`:

```
for key, value in student_score.items():
    print(key, ' : ', value)
```

the output looks like this:

```
Sam  :  7
John  :  10
Aadi  :  8
```

All you have to do is use a for loop to iterate through the dictionary.

Comment: Use this `print ('"{0}": {1}'.format(key, value))` instead of  `print(key, ' : ', value)` :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, python automatically translates `\n` to the proper newline character.

```
d = {"id": 12345, "msg": "Some msgs \n from the \n text file"}
for i in d:
    print ('"{0}": {1}'.format(i, d[i]))
```

and you can add `\t` for additional indentation.