# Python's equivalent for R's dput() function

Tags: python, r

Is there any function in python similar to [dput() function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/dput.html) in R?

Comment: Perhaps the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41189949/850781

Answer (score 29):

for a `pandas.DataFrame`, `print(df.to_dict())`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450931/print-pandas-data-frame-for-reproducible-example-equivalent-to-dput-in-r).

And back again with `df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data_as_dict)`

Comment: Great answer! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @PatrickT, do you know how to do that with other objects such as `dictionaries`?

Comment: If I understand your question, `print(d)` will do that. You can also output the keys and the values separately with `d.keys()` and `d.values()`. Maybe your question is more involved? Look at this perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229419/how-to-pretty-print-nested-dictionaries

Answer (score 13):

There are several options for serializing Python objects to files:

- `json.dump()` stores the data in JSON format. It is very read- and editable, but can only store lists, dicts, strings, numbers, booleans, so no compound objects. You need to `import json` before to make the `json` module available.
- `pickle.dump()` can store most objects.

Less common:

- The `shelve` module stores multiple Python objects in a DBM database, mostly acting like a persistent `dict`.
- `marshal.dump()`: Not sure when you'd ever need that.

Comment: As this is a beginner's question would you please clarify if it requires to ``import json`` or something similar. Also I tried it on a ``pandas.DataFrame`` and got ``dump() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'`` ...

Comment: Could you illustrate with an example, @ChristianAichinger? I agree with what @PatrickT said since I am getting the same error `dump() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'`

Answer (score 11):

How no one has mentioned `repr()` yet is a mystery to me. `repr()` does almost exactly what R's `dput()` does. Here's a few examples:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> repr(a)
'array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])'
>>> d = dict(x=1, y=2)
>>> repr(d)
"{'x': 1, 'y': 2}"
>>> b = range(10)
>>> repr(b)
'range(0, 10)'
```

Comment: agreer with @JonasV, this is the correct answer

Comment: It is still inferior to `dput` because it does not keep the data type of the columns :/

Answer (score 7):

This answer focuses on `json.dump()` and `json.dumps()` and how to use them with numpy arrays. If you try, Python will hit you with an error saying that ndarrays are not JSON serializable:

```
import numpy as np
import json

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
json.dumps(a)
```

> ```
> TypeError: Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable
> ```

You can avoid this by translating it to a list first. See below for two working examples:

#### `json.dumps()`

`json.dumps()` seems to be the closest to R's `dput()` since it allows you to copy-paste the result straight from the console:

```
json.dumps(a.tolist()) # '[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]'
```

#### `json.dump()`

`json.dump()` is not the same as `dput()` but it's still very useful. `json.dump()` will encode your object to a json file.

```
# Encode:
savehere = open('file_location.json', 'w')
json.dump(a.tolist(), savehere)
```

which you can then decode elsewhere:

```
# Decode:
b = open('file_location.json', 'r').read()   # b is '[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]'
c = json.loads(b)
```

Then you can transform it back a numpy array again:

```
c = np.array(c)
```

### More information

on avoiding the 'not serializable' error see:

- [numpy array is not json serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646362/numpy-array-is-not-json-serializable)
- [how to make classes json serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable) (kind of unrelated, but very interesting)

Comment: Thanks, what would be the correct parameter to obtain matrices formatted with one line per row in the matrix, as the standard `numpy.array` output? I tried to pass the `indent` and `separators` parameters to `json.dumps` without success.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, `json.dumps()` (note the **s**) is even better since it returns a string, as opposed to `json.dump()` which requires you to write to a file.

Comment: Could you provide more details on how to use this?