# how to perform subplot in loop for seaborn charts

Tags: python, loops, graph, seaborn

I have code that generates four subplots, but i want to generate those charts through loops , Currently i am following this piece of code to generate the chart
Code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 12))
plt.subplot(221)
sns.barplot(x = 'Category', y = 'POG_Added', data = df)
xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.xticks(size = 11)
plt.yticks(size = 11)
plt.xlabel("Category",size = 13)
plt.ylabel("POG_Added",size = 13)

plt.subplot(222)
sns.barplot(x = 'Category', y = 'Live_POG', data = df)
xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.xticks(size = 11)
plt.yticks(size = 11)
plt.xlabel("Category",size = 13)
plt.ylabel("Live_POG",size = 13)

plt.subplot(223)
sns.lineplot(x = 'Category', y = 'D01_CVR', data = df)
#sns.barplot(x = 'Category', y = 'D2-08-Visits', data = df,label='D2-08_Visits')
xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.xticks(size = 11)
plt.yticks(size = 11)
plt.xlabel("Category",size = 13)
plt.ylabel("D01_CVR",size = 13)

plt.subplot(224)

plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
ax = sns.barplot(x='Category',y='D2-08-Units',data=df)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(), df["D01_CVR"], alpha = .75, color = 'r')

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.55,wspace=0.55)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `to_clipboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-do-i-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-my-existing-dataframe)

Comment: Alternatively, [please provide a reproducible copy of DataFrame with Python equilvalent of R's `dput`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418895/pythons-equivalent-for-rs-dput-function).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do things like that:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [np.random.random((10, 10)) for _ in range(6)]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=2, figsize=(9, 6))
for ax, dat in zip(axs.ravel(), data):
    ax.imshow(dat)
```

This produces:

[image: matplotlib output]

The idea is that `plt.subplots()` produces an array of `Axes` objects, so you can loop over it and make your plots in the loop. In this case I need `ndarray.ravel()` because `axs` is a 2D array.

Comment: If you see closely, OP runs different graphs per plot and even one with dual axes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider tightening up repetitive code by:

- Set unchanging aesthetics like all x-ticks and y-ticks font sizes in one call with [`plt.rc`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.rc.html) calls.
- Build [`plt.subplots()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) and use its array of Axes objects.
- Use `ax` argument of seaborn's [`barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) and [`lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) to loop above Axes array.

While not completely DRY given the special two plots, below is adjustment:

```
# AXES AND TICKS FONT SIZES
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=11)
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=11)
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=13)

# FIGURE AND SUBPLOTS SETUP
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(20, 12))

# BAR PLOTS (FIRST ROW)
for i, col in enumerate(['POG_Added', 'Live_POG']):
    sns.barplot(x='Category', y=col, data=df, ax=axes[0,i])
    axes[0,i].tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)

# LINE PLOT 
sns.lineplot(x='Category', y='D01_CVR', data=df, ax=axes[1,0])
axes[1,0].tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)

# BAR + LINE DUAL PLOT
sns.barplot(x='Category', y='D2-08-Units', data=df, ax=axes[1,1])
ax2 = axes[1,1].twinx()
ax2.plot(axes[1,1].get_xticks(), df["D01_CVR"], alpha = .75, color = 'r')
axes[1,1].tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)
```