# Box plot are overlapping because of same name

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, boxplot

```
for design in list
    if len(design) > 12:
        df["Name"] = str(design)[:12] + str("...")

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Box(
            x=df["Name"],
            y=df[y_variable],
            name="",
            quartilemethod=quartile_method,
            boxpoints=False,
        )
```

so if i have 2 names in the list
name1 = ABCDEFGHIJKL
name2 = ABCDEFGHIJKLM

after truncation
name1 = ABCDEFGHIJKL
name2 = ABCDEFGHIJKL

so both become same in x.

Overlapping box blot with same x

[image]

How to overcome this?
I tried using unique identifier but at the same time I want to have same in the x axis

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/8107362). Especially, provide some [sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22418895/8107362), e.g. with `print(df.to_dict())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- reusing https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/#box-plot-with-plotlyexpress as basis for re-runnable example
- simulated the issue you noted,  where x values overlap
- resolved, by

  1. not truncating x value
  2. resolved by updating **xaxis** ticks so that truncated value is displayed and bar plots are maintained

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.tips()
df["name"] = df["time"].map({"Dinner": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO", "Lunch": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"})

go.Figure(
    [
        go.Box(
            x=df.loc[df["name"].eq(n), "name"].str[0:12],
            y=df.loc[df["name"].eq(n), "total_bill"],
            name=n,
            boxpoints=False
        )
        for n in df["name"].unique()
    ]
).show()


go.Figure(
    [
        go.Box(
            x=df.loc[df["name"].eq(n), "name"],
            y=df.loc[df["name"].eq(n), "total_bill"],
            name=n,
            boxpoints=False
        )
        for n in df["name"].unique()
    ]
).update_layout(xaxis=dict(tickmode="array", tickvals=df.loc[:, "name"], ticktext=df.loc[:, "name"].str[0:12]))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any possibility to append/remove text from hover text coming over the plot?
can we show different text in hover text from x ticks text like ABCDEFGHIJK.
ex. having ABCDEFGHIJK in x axis ticks but ABCDEFGHIJK123 in hovertext over the plot

Comment: your sample code was using graph objects so I used.  `px.box(df, x=df["name"].str[0:12], y="total_bill", color="name", hover_name="name", points="all")` is same solution with Plotly Express .  the hover info is only on points scatter, not the quartiles.  it's obviously in the color and legend

Comment: Thanks @Rob Raymond

Comment: is it possible to have a boxplot for single point?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70970008/boxplot-for-single-point