# BoxPlot for single point

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, boxplot, plotly-python

When there is only one point in the data, box plot is coming empty. But what I am expecting is a degenrated plot  which shows horizontal line corresponding to that point.
Is it possible to do so?
attaching sample data code which I tried

```
data1 = {'A':["Favorite"],
        'B':[0.413]}

data= pd.DataFrame(data1)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
            go.Box(
                x=data["A"],
                y=data["B"],
                name="",
                quartilemethod='exclusive',
                boxpoints=False,
                marker_color='#00528c',
            )
        )
```

I am getting something below
[image]

But what I am expecting is something like a line corresponding to single point
[image]

Thanks for your response!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extend your sample code to work with various sized arrays.  Simple answer has to be >= 2 items to generate a box plot. https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/#box-plot-with-plotlyexpress *A box plot is a statistical representation of the distribution of a variable through its quartiles.* A list length 1 is not a distribution.

```
S = 2
data1 = {'A':np.repeat(["Favorite"], S),
        'B':np.repeat([0.413], S) * np.random.uniform(.98,1.02, S)}

data= pd.DataFrame(data1)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
            go.Box(
                x=data["A"],
                y=data["B"],
                name="",
                quartilemethod='exclusive',
                boxpoints=False,
                marker_color='#00528c',
            )
        )
```

Comment: How about hovertext? can we have hovertext also for single line which represent median i guess?

Comment: if array size >= 2 then you get a median on boxplot.  see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70966883/how-to-specify-the-percentiles-in-a-pyplot-box/70975264#70975264 where lines can be added to box plots as well,   These too will have hover text