# Plotting a pandas dataframe using column names as x axis

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Pandas Dataframe]

I have the following Pandas Dataframe (linked above) and I'd like to plot a graph with the values `1.0 - 39.0`  on the x axis and the y axis would be the dataframe values in the column of these (`-0.004640` etc). The rows are other lines I'd like to plot, so at the end there will be a lot of lines.

I've tried to transpose my plot but that doesn't seem to work.

**How could I go about doing this?**

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/8107362). Especially, provide some [sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22418895/8107362) in a ready-to-use format, e.g. with `print(df.to_dict())`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x=[1.0, 39.0]
plt.plot(x, df[1.0])
plt.plot(x, df[2.0})
...
```