# How to remove all excessive spaces in any csv file read by Pandas without specifying columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, collections

My plan is to display an Ordered dictionary with OrderedDict of a dataframe read from any csv with or without excessive spaces (initial spaces/non initial spaces, excessive spaces(double/tripe spaces) in between words)

These are the problems I encountered while trying to get rid of excessive spaces:

1. By using `str.strip()`, the string of columns are needed to be specified, which can only work with specific csv file.
2. By specifying `sep` in the parameter of `pd.read_csv`, some of the items in the csv file will turn into 'None' in an ordered dictionary.
3. `skipinitialspace()` can't remove other excessive spaces.

Any workaround for this code?:

```
file = input("Input any csv file or file path \nYour input: ")

df = pd.read_csv(file)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
      d = OrderedDict(zip(row.index.tolist(), row.tolist()))
      print(d)
```

Edit:

Additional example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[f'Ka te', f' Rose '], [f' Tim ', f'John  son'], [f'James  ', f'House  ']], columns=['First Name', 'Last Name'])

for i, row in df.iterrows():
      d = OrderedDict(zip(row.index.tolist(), row.tolist()))
      print(d)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('First Name', 'Ka te'), ('Last Name', ' Rose ')])
OrderedDict([('First Name', ' Tim '), ('Last Name', 'John  son')])
OrderedDict([('First Name', 'James  '), ('Last Name', 'House  ')])
```

The Output that I want:

```
OrderedDict([('First Name', 'Kate'), ('Last Name', 'Rose')])
OrderedDict([('First Name', 'Tim'), ('Last Name', 'John son')])
OrderedDict([('First Name', 'James'), ('Last Name', 'House')])
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/8107362). Especially, provide some [sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22418895/8107362) and your expected result, e.g. with `print(df.to_dict())`. I understand that the cleaning does not need to happen when loading the data?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have edited the post with some additional information added, I am not sure what to do as I am still a new learner.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the solution, it can be achieved by using str.replace():

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[f'Ka te', f' Rose '], [f' Tim ', f'John  son'], [f'James  ', f'House  ']], columns=['First Name', 'Last Name'])

for c in df:
  df[c] = df[c].str.replace(' ', '')

for i, row in df.iterrows():
  d = OrderedDict(zip(row.index.tolist(), row.tolist()))
  print(d)
```