# where() function explanation needed on Series Vs DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

df has Columns A,B,C,D,E , assume column "A" is a string and rest are numbers.

`df["A"].where(df[B] > 100).dropna()` returning Column "A" wherever "B" has value > 100

my question is that `df["A"]` (it's a view of original df) does not have column "B", then how can "where" clause applied with Column B. [where() clause is applied on `df["A"]` but not on entire "df"]

type of `df["A"]` is a Pandas Series, even then `where()` clause on column "B" is bit confusing how this get applied.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/8107362). Especially, provide some [sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22418895/8107362), e.g. with `print(df.to_dict())`.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to get all the columns of the dataframe, instead of just `A`.

Just remove the `["A"]` part:

```py
df["A"].where(df["B"] > 100).dropna()
```

to

```py
df.where(df["B"] > 100).dropna()
```

Now you can do something like this:

```py
>>> subset = df.where(df["B"] > 100).dropna()
>>> subset["B"]
...
>>> subset["A"]
```

---

Note: instead of using `where` + `dropna`, a shorter, equivalent solution to the above would be the following.

Instead of

```py
df.where(df["B"] > 100).dropna()
```

just use

```py
df[df["B"] > 100]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. may be I have not framed my question correctly, when where() function is applied on df["A"] (is a subset of original df) and inside where clause checking another column "B" , how can column "B" can be refereced on df["A"] since it does not have column B.

Comment: You framed your question correctly. If you remove the `["A"]` part, you can do something like `df.where(df["B"] > 100).dropna()["A"]` or `df.where(df["B"] > 100).dropna()["B"]`.