# How to Add a list to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I know this question has been asked before, but I've tried to implement all the solutions I've found and still haven't solved the problem.

Here is my code

```
import csv

import pandas as pd

import helperFunctions import pandas tickers = []

f = open("watchlist.txt", "r") for i in f:
    tickers.append((helperFunctions.getTicker(i)))

head = ["Name", "Growth", "Recommendation", "Earnings Growth", "Current Ratio",
        "Total Cash", "Debt", " Revenue", "Percentage Shares Out", "Percentage Institutions", "Percentage Insiders",
        "Price to Book", "Short Ratio", "Regular Market Price"] df = pd.DataFrame() df = pd.DataFrame(columns=head) try:
    for i in tickers:
        currentTicker = []
        currentTicker.append(i.info['longName'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['revenueGrowth'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['recommendationKey'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['earningsGrowth'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['currentRatio'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['totalCash'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['totalDebt'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['totalRevenue'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['sharesPercentSharesOut'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['heldPercentInstitutions'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['heldPercentInsiders'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['priceToBook'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['shortRatio'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['beta'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['regularMarketPrice'])
        print(str(currentTicker + "\n"))
        '''
        # Why Don't these work??
        1.
        df.append(currentTicker)
        
        2.
        df_length = len(df)
        df.loc[df_length] = currentTicker
        
        3.
        a_series = pd.Series(currentTicker, index=df.columns)
        df = df.append(a_series, ignore_index=True)
        
        '''

except Exception as e:
    print(str(i) + repr(e))

print(df)
```

In the section where you see comments in the list, those are all things things  I've attempted to add each iteration to the dataframe. Basically the watchlist is a txtfile with some tickers, and I would like to get that data and put it into a dataframe and I'm running into some trouble. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible **minimal** example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/8107362). Especially, provide some [sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22418895/8107362), e.g. with `print(df.to_dict())`.

Comment: The sample data is gotten from the txt file that looks like
aapl
msft
tsla
etc..

it will produce lists that look like this 
['Apple Inc.', 0.288, 'buy', 0.662, 1.075, 62639001600, 136521998336, 365817004032, 0.0061000003, 0.58697, 0.00071000005, 40.825306, 1.5, 1.205714, 156.81]

Comment: that print statement produces this:

{'Name': {}, 'Growth': {}, 'Recommendation': {}, 'Earnings Growth': {}, 'Current Ratio': {}, 'Total Cash': {}, 'Debt': {}, ' Revenue': {}, 'Percentage Shares Out': {}, 'Percentage Institutions': {}, 'Percentage Insiders': {}, 'Price to Book': {}, 'Short Ratio': {}, 'Regular Market Price': {}}

Comment: have you tried reading csv directly from pandas? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not reading it in as a csv, ultimately I'd like to send it out as a csv

Comment: would be good to have the actual data (the one you give seems wrong: would expect this format:[[...],[...]]. And you could try pd.DataFrame(data=your_data, columns=your_columns)

Comment: I'll try that out, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This was how I ended up solving it

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import helperFunctions
import pandas
tickers = []

f = open("watchlist.txt", "r")
for i in f:
    tickers.append((helperFunctions.getTicker(i)))

head = ["Name", "Growth", "Recommendation", "Earnings Growth", "Current Ratio",
        "Total Cash", "Debt", "Revenue", "Percentage Shares Out", "Percentage Institutions", "Percentage Insiders",
        "Price to Book", "Short Ratio", "Regular Market Price"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=head)
try:
    for i in tickers:
        currentTicker = []
        currentTicker.append(i.info['longName'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['revenueGrowth'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['recommendationKey'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['earningsGrowth'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['currentRatio'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['totalCash'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['totalDebt'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['totalRevenue'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['sharesPercentSharesOut'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['heldPercentInstitutions'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['heldPercentInsiders'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['priceToBook'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['shortRatio'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['beta'])
        currentTicker.append(i.info['regularMarketPrice'])

        df = df.append({'Name': currentTicker[0],
                        'Growth': currentTicker[1],
                        "Recommendation":currentTicker[2],
                        "Earnings Growth":currentTicker[3],
                        "Current Ratio": currentTicker[4],
                        "Total Cash":currentTicker[5],
                        "Debt": currentTicker[6],
                        "Revenue": currentTicker[7],
                        "Percentage Shares Out": currentTicker[8],
                        "Percentage Institutions": currentTicker[9],
                        "Percentage Insiders": currentTicker[10],
                        "Price to Book": currentTicker[11],
                        "Short Ratio": currentTicker[12],
                        "Regular Market Price": currentTicker[13],
                        },
                       ignore_index=True)
        #print(currentTicker)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(i) + repr(e))

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code seems to be related to the fact that the `currentTicker` list has an extra column, namely `beta`, which is not present in the columns of the `df`.

Once you either add that column to `head` or remove it from `currentTicker`, method 2 and 3 will work.

```py
import csv

import pandas as pd

import helperFunctions

with open("watchlist.txt", "r") as f:
    tickers = [helperFunctions.getTicker(i) for i in f]

head = [
    "Name",
    "Growth",
    "Recommendation",
    "Earnings Growth",
    "Current Ratio",
    "Total Cash",
    "Debt",
    "Revenue",
    "Percentage Shares Out",
    "Percentage Institutions",
    "Percentage Insiders",
    "Price to Book",
    "Short Ratio",
    "Regular Market Price"
]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=head)

columns_to_extract = [
    'longName',
    'revenueGrowth',
    'recommendationKey',
    'earningsGrowth',
    'currentRatio',
    'totalCash',
    'totalDebt',
    'totalRevenue',
    'sharesPercentSharesOut',
    'heldPercentInstitutions',
    'heldPercentInsiders',
    'priceToBook',
    'shortRatio',
    # 'beta', # <- The column for this value is missing from `head`
    'regularMarketPrice'
]

currentTicker = [i.info[key] for key in columns_to_extract]

# 1. Method - THIS DOES NOT WORK
# df.append(currentTicker)

# 2. Method
df_length = len(df)
df.loc[df_length] = currentTicker

# 3. Method
a_series = pd.Series(currentTicker, index=df.columns)
df = df.append(a_series, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```