# Is there a function in python similar to dput in R

Tags: python, dictionary

IS there a way to reproduce the below dictionary

```
dict
Out[2]: {1: {'Geeks': [[1, 'N', None]], 'Geeks1': [[1, None, 'H']]}}
```

Now is there a way to reproduce this. Like what we have in R(dput) so that even when there is large keys and values, we can replicate dictionary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python's equivalent for R's dput() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418895/pythons-equivalent-for-rs-dput-function)