# Concise way to print dictionary keys in a nice format

Tags: python, dictionary

I'd like to get a nice output of all keys (and possibly subkeys) within a dictionary. Hence I wrote:

```
print("The keys in this dictionary are:\n")
for k in mydict.keys():
    print(k)
```

This works, however is there a more concise way to do this? I tried list comprehension, however this of course returns a list which I can't concatenate with may introduction string. Anything more functional that could be used?

EDIT:
The dictionary might look like this:

```
mydict = {'key1':'value1',
          'key2':{'subkey1':'subvalue1','subkey2':'subvalue2'}}
```

I'm open to the meaning of 'nice formatting'. However, maybe something like this:

```
key1
key2: subkey1, subkey2
```

Comment: Some of the values of the keys are dictionaries themselves, so I'd like to print them too

Comment: How about using `join`? e.g. `print "\n".join(mydict.keys())`. That will help with a single dictionary, but not subkeys.

Comment: @pandita Could you please provide an example of such a dictionary? Please also describe what is "nice" for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def dump_keys(d, lvl=0):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        print '%s%s' % (lvl * ' ', k)
        if type(v) == dict:
            dump_keys(v, lvl+1)

mydict = {'key1':'value1',
          'key2':{'subkey1':'subvalue1',
                  'subkey2':'subvalue2',
                  'subkey3': {'subsubkey1' : 'subsubkeyval1'}}}

dump_keys(mydict)
```

Comment: Nice one! Do you know of a way to do this directly with a pprint command?

Answer (score 2):

If you want concise code, try the [pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module.

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(data)
```

There are some other solutions for nested dictionaries here: [pretty printing nested dictionaries in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229419/pretty-printing-nested-dictionaries-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest print it in

```
import json
json.dumps(dict, indent=4)
```

Comment: This will only work if all the objects in your dictionary are JSON serializable, i.e. no numpy arrays nor lambda functions for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You in fact can concatenate your list with your introduction string.Try this :

```
print "The keys in my dictionary are: " + ','.join([k for k in mydict.keys()])
```

*This would work only for non nested dictionaries though