# Dict from CSV formatting

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary, formatting, code-formatting

I'm trying to import a CSV file as a dictionary in python but with a set layout.

My code  below works

CSV file

```
key1, value1
Key2, value2
```

Script

```
Import cvs
with open('test.csv', mode='r') as infile:

    with open('dict.py', mode='w') as outfile:
        mydict = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}
        output.write(mydict)
```

So my output looks like

```
{'Key1': 'value1', 'Key2': 'value2'}
```

How can I make it look like

```
{
'Key1': 'value1', 
'Key2': 'value2',
}
```

Basically on a newline each?

P.s sorry about formatting done on mobile app

Comment: use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pretty printing nested dictionaries in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229419/pretty-printing-nested-dictionaries-in-python)

Comment: No not a duplicate as im not wanting to indent nor use pretty print.

Comment: If you read through the answers several [do not use pretty print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229419/pretty-printing-nested-dictionaries-in-python/3314411#3314411) (the activestate one is almost a direct quote of what you are trying to do) and most of them include settings for indentation or lack thereof.

Comment: Noted and shall re read

Comment: Thanks @JGeenwell found one and used it.