# How to create multidimensional dictionary of unknown depth based on lookup dictionary? (python)

Tags: python

I have this "lookup" dictionary, which represents nodes:

```
# Original "lookup" dictionary

{
  0 : [1, 2],
  2 : [3],
  4 : [5]
}
```

...and I wish to create a new dictionary based on this, like so:

```
# New multidimensional dictionary

{
  0 : {
        1 : {},
        2 : {
              3 : {}
            }
      }
  4 : {
        5 : {}
      }
  }
}
```

How can this be achieved using recursion?

The original "lookup" dictionary's **keys** represent parent nodes and the **values** represent children nodes in one or more node trees.

The original "lookup" dictionary contains an unknown amount of keys/values and the depth is unknown.

Comment: To express the purpose of the original dict: it describes parent-child relationships with the keys being the parents and the values being the children?!

Comment: @deceze Yes, correct.

Comment: This sounds (reads) like a recursion problem. Use a function that calls itself. Have you tried that?

Comment: There are several implementations here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229419/pretty-printing-nested-dictionaries-in-python

Comment: @tglaria yes but I don't understand how to recursively add a new key at a given depth.

Comment: @fredrik, well it's just `new_dict[some_key] = some_value`. So if the present value is a list, you add its value to the dictionnary, if not, then you add a new dictionnary.

Comment: Is this supposed to result in a tree, or something else?  Your sample data appears to have two roots: `0` and `4`, implying it's a "forest" (several trees), or that the tree has an assumed "invisible root" that's a parent of all roots, or that you're actually trying to create a DAG, or...

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase It's supposed to result in a "forest", which is how the accepted answer deals with it.

Comment: Thanks fredrik, that cleared it up.  I couldn't figure out why you'd accepted an answer that started off by assuming you wanted a tree, when your example output clearly _wasn't_ a tree.  Or at least, wasn't _one_ tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that this data structure represents a tree, and that nodes are numbered so that the parent always has a lower index than the children. Then, you can build the tree you want without recursion, with the help of a helper index (`nodeindex`) that lets you find each node in one step:

```
tree = dict()
nodeindex = dict()
for node, vals in sorted(lookup.items()):
    if node not in nodeindex:
        nodeindex[node] = tree[node] = dict()  # insert at the top level

    position = nodeindex[node]
    for val in vals:
        if val in nodeindex:
            raise ValueError("Value (%d, %d) would create a loop!" %(node, val))
        nodeindex[val] = position[val] = dict()
```

If a non-tree graph is legal, the last part of the loop would assign to `position[val]` the value it found, instead of raising an error:

```
    ...
    for val in vals:
        if val in nodeindex:
            position[val] = nodeindex[val]
        else:
            nodeindex[val] = position[val] = dict()
```

Comment: I know you're not supposed to comment to say "thanks" etc... but that was an awesome solution. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! In my experience it's tolerated in comments-- just leave the thanks out of the questions and answers :-)