# Splitting by ',' in a dictionary while retaining the lists inside

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split

I've been looking for a way to split by ',' in a dictionary while retaining the present lists but have not been succesful. I want to split this dictionary:

```
{'R_ARABR': ['YHR104W'], 'R_GLYCt': ['YLL043W'], 'R_LPP_SC': ['YDR284C', 'YDR503C'], 'R_TREH': ['YDR001C', 'YBR001C'], 'R_CTPS2': ['YBL039C', 'YJR103W'], 'R_CTPS1': ['YBL039C', 'YJR103W']}
```

To appear like this:

```
{'R_ARABR': ['YHR104W'],
'R_GLYCt': ['YLL043W'],
'R_LPP_SC': ['YDR284C', 'YDR503C'],
'R_TREH': ['YDR001C', 'YBR001C'],
'R_CTPS2': ['YBL039C', 'YJR103W'],
'R_CTPS1': ['YBL039C', 'YJR103W']}
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: What are you splitting? You have a dict with lists and you seem to want the same output as you already have

Comment: It seems you just want to pretty print the dictionary? Is it so?

Comment: Indeed, I want a more readable format for this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pprint.pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint), eg:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> d = {'R_ARABR': ['YHR104W'], 'R_GLYCt': ['YLL043W'], 'R_LPP_SC': ['YDR284C', 'YDR503C'], 'R_TREH': ['YDR001C', 'YBR001C'], 'R_CTPS2': ['YBL039C', 'YJR103W'], 'R_CTPS1': ['YBL039C', 'YJR103W']}
>>> pprint.pprint(d)
{'R_ARABR': ['YHR104W'],
 'R_CTPS1': ['YBL039C', 'YJR103W'],
 'R_CTPS2': ['YBL039C', 'YJR103W'],
 'R_GLYCt': ['YLL043W'],
 'R_LPP_SC': ['YDR284C', 'YDR503C'],
 'R_TREH': ['YDR001C', 'YBR001C']}
```

If you want to get the result as a string to then use elsewhere (maybe write to a file), then use [`pprint.pformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat) as `pprint.pprint` writes directly to stdout and returns `None`.

Comment: Related [pretty printing nested dictionaries in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3229419)

Comment: This indeed works in the console. I want to write it to a .txt file. Unfortunately, it writes 'none'. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Cheeseburgler updated answer