# How to print out a dictionary nicely in Python?

Tags: python

I've just started to learn python and I'm building a text game. I want an inventory system, but I can't seem to print out the dictionary without it looking ugly.

This is what I have so far:

```
def inventory():
    for numberofitems in len(inventory_content.keys()):
        inventory_things = list(inventory_content.keys())
        inventory_amounts = list(inventory_content.values())
        print(inventory_things[numberofitems])
```

Comment: _"nicely"_ is a subjective term, but perhaps you are looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229419/pretty-printing-nested-dictionaries-in-python).

Comment: FYI, this sample code doesn't work at all. The `for` loop here will be an error. I think you meant to use a `range`. Also, `inventory_amounts` isn't used, so you aren't printing the values.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229419/how-to-pretty-print-nested-dictionaries

Answer (score 189, accepted):

I like the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module (Pretty Print) included in Python. It can be used to either print the object, or format a nice string version of it.

```
import pprint

# Prints the nicely formatted dictionary
pprint.pprint(dictionary)

# Sets 'pretty_dict_str' to the formatted string value
pretty_dict_str = pprint.pformat(dictionary)
```

But it sounds like you are printing out an inventory, which users will likely want shown as something more like the following:

```
def print_inventory(dct):
    print("Items held:")
    for item, amount in dct.items():  # dct.iteritems() in Python 2
        print("{} ({})".format(item, amount))

inventory = {
    "shovels": 3,
    "sticks": 2,
    "dogs": 1,
}

print_inventory(inventory)
```

which prints:

```
Items held:
shovels (3)
sticks (2)
dogs (1)
```

Comment: or `from pprint import pprint; pprint(dictionary)` ... +1

Comment: Had to use: for item, amount in dct.items(): instead of: for item, amount in dct.iteritems():

Comment: Hi, does this work if I want to save the output as a .txt file? Will it be saved in that format?

Comment: to keep the printing format of pprint, you can use `import pprint as pp` the n call `pp.pformat(object)` to keep its string structure for logging, saving, etc...

Comment: You may need to use `pprint.pprint(dictionary, sort_dicts=False)` if dictionary order matters.

Answer (score 115):

My favorite way:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: Note that `sort_keys=True` throws an error if there are keys that are of different types (eg. integer and string keys).

Comment: Your dictionary must only contain JSON-serializable objects, which are strings, various numbers, and booleans, for this to work. If that's the case, this is the easiest way with the nicest formatting.

Comment: @sudo you can use `default=str` so if something is not JSON-serializable it is first converted to a string

Comment: Can it be sorted based on values?

Answer (score 31):

Here's the one-liner I'd use. (Edit: works for things that aren't JSON-serializable too)

```
print("\n".join("{}\t{}".format(k, v) for k, v in dictionary.items()))
```

Explanation: This iterates through the keys and values of the dictionary, creating a formatted string like key + tab + value for each. And `"\n".join(...` puts newlines between all those strings, forming a new string.

Example:

```
>>> dictionary = {1: 2, 4: 5, "foo": "bar"}
>>> print("\n".join("{}\t{}".format(k, v) for k, v in dictionary.items()))
1   2
4   5
foo bar
>>>
```

Edit 2: Here's a sorted version.

```
"\n".join("{}\t{}".format(k, v) for k, v in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda t: str(t[0])))
```

Comment: Can it be sorted based on the values?

Comment: @alper Yes, with something like `"\n".join("{}\t{}".format(k, v) for k, v in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda t: str(t[0])))`

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest to use [beeprint](https://github.com/panyanyany/beeprint) instead of pprint.

Examples:

**pprint**

```
{'entities': {'hashtags': [],
              'urls': [{'display_url': 'github.com/panyanyany/beeprint',
                        'indices': [107, 126],
                        'url': 'https://github.com/panyanyany/beeprint'}],
              'user_mentions': []}}
```

**beeprint**

```
{
  'entities': {
    'hashtags': [],
    'urls': [
      {
        'display_url': 'github.com/panyanyany/beeprint',
        'indices': [107, 126],
        'url': 'https://github.com/panyanyany/beeprint'}],
      },
    ],
    'user_mentions': [],
  },
}
```

Comment: but how do you use it? I tried `from beeprint import pp` just like in the doc, then tried calling pp(dictionary_name) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Yaml is typically much more readable, especially if you have complicated nested objects, hierarchies, nested dictionaries etc:

First make sure you have pyyaml module:

```
pip install pyyaml
```

Then,

```
import yaml
print(yaml.dump(my_dict))
```

Comment: `sudo apt install python-yaml` for Ubuntu 16.04 users. There is a small flaw when a dictionary value string contains `,` but that is minor output flaw. Otherwise a great tool.

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.6 you can use f-strings to write @sudo's one-liner even more compact

```
print("\n".join(f"{k}\t{v}" for k, v in dictionary.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree, "nicely" is very subjective. See if this helps, which I have been using to debug dict

```
for i in inventory_things.keys():
    logger.info('Key_Name:"{kn}", Key_Value:"{kv}"'.format(kn=i, kv=inventory_things[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function to print simple dictionaries:

```
def dictToString(dict):
  return str(dict).replace(', ','\r\n').replace("u'","").replace("'","")[1:-1]
```

Comment: In some cases, such as `{"abc, abc": 123, "def": 456}`, will work incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I did create function (in Python 3):

```
def print_dict(dict):
    print(

    str(dict)
    .replace(', ', '\n')
    .replace(': ', ':\t')
    .replace('{', '')
    .replace('}', '')

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't fit all the needs but I just tried this and it got a nice formatted output
So just convert the dictionary to Dataframe and that's pretty much all

```
pd.DataFrame(your_dic.items())
```

You can also define columns to assist even more the readability

```
pd.DataFrame(your_dic.items(),columns={'Value','key'})
```

So just give a try :

```
print(pd.DataFrame(your_dic.items(),columns={'Value','key'}))
```