# Need some help in formatting strings in Python

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I am trying to get an output similar to this.

```
{
  "Continent": "Asia",
  "Country": "Japan" 
}
```

The code below is throwing an error.

```
    var = "Japan"
message_body_3 = '{\n  \"Continent\": \"Asia\",\n  \"Country\": \"{0}\" \n} '.format(var)
```

Error:

```
    message_body_3 = '{\n  \"Continent\": \"Asia\",\n  \"Country\": \" {0} \" \n} '.format(var)
KeyError: '\n  "Continent"'
```

I want the {0} to be replaced with my variable.

What's the best way to achieve the result. I need to have backslashes and quotes in my string. Is there any way to do this in python ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I print literal curly-brace characters in a string and also use .format on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466451/how-can-i-print-literal-curly-brace-characters-in-a-string-and-also-use-format)

Comment: "I tried f strings but they don't support backslashes.". Show what you did with all error tracebacks or it never happened

Comment: @MadPhysicist `f'{"hello\n"}'` results in: `SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash`.

Comment: message_body_3 = '{{\n  \"Continent\": \"Asia\",\n  \"Country\": \"{0}\" \n}} '.format("Japan")
print(message_body_3)

Comment: You should use `pprint` and a dictionary, not manually putting in newline characters to a string

Comment: @WaseemRandhawa How do I write, if I have one more layer in the string:

message_body_3 = '{{\n \"Continent\": \"Asia\",\n \"Country\": \" {0}   \" \n \"Address\" : { \n     \"State\":  \" {1} \" \n     \"City\":  \"  {2} \"  \n  }\n}}'.format(var1,var2,var3).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229419/how-to-pretty-print-nested-dictionaries

Comment: message_body_3 = '{{\n \"Continent\": \"Asia\",\n \"Country\": \"{0}\", \n \"Continent\": \"Asia\"}} '.format("Japan")
print(message_body_3)

Comment: message_body_3 = '{{\n \"Continent\": \"Asia\",\n \"Country\": \" {0} \" \n \"Address\" :{{\n\"State\": \" {1} \" \n \"City\": \" {2} \"\n}} \n}}'.format('var1','var2','var3')
print(message_body_3)

Comment: You can use `{{` for literal braces, or do `'{' + f'...' + '}\n'`

Comment: The error is because you need to tell the f-string that `{` is literal, not a replacement in that case. Hence the duplicate.