# Сonvert dict or json formats with nested objects into string

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

Now I have a string in format dict but as i can guess its a json format its look like:

```json
{
   "gid":"1201400250397201",
   "memberships":[
      "can be nested objects",
      ...
   ],
   "name":"Name of task",
   "parent":{
      "gid":"1201400250397199",
      "name":"name of parent task"
   },
   "permalink_url":"https://url...."
}
```

1. So first question: am i right? I used `dumps()` from json library but got unicode escape sequences, `loads()` didnt work for me, i got error "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict".
2. Second  question: if its not json format, how can i get comfortable view? I did it:
   first of all i get dict-line, then I print a dictionary's key:

   > ```
   > for key in task:
   >     task
   >     print(task[key])
   > ```

   output:

   > ```
   > 1201400250397201
   > []
   > Name of task
   > {'gid': '1201400250397199', 'name': ''name of parent task'}
   > https://url....
   > ```

At actually it would be great if I get something like that:

```
gid: 1201400250397201
name: Name of task
parent_name: 'Name of task' etc
```

But I dont know how to get it :(

Next question: as you can see for part "parent" (penultimate line) I also get dictionary, how can I extract it and get convenient format?
Or maybe you have your comfortable methods?

Comment: Python objects are not JSON. In order to pretty-print a Python object, use the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pretty print nested dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229419/how-to-pretty-print-nested-dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

Like stated in your error, the object you are working with is already a dictionary. You can print it directly as json with `json.dumps`:

```
task = {'gid': '1201400250397201', 'memberships': [{}], 'name': 'Name of task', 'parent': {'gid': '1201400250397199', 'name': 'name of parent task'},'permalink_url': 'https://url....'}
print(json.dumps(task, indent=4))
```

Setting `indent=4` makes it readable and you'll get:

```
{
    "gid": "1201400250397201",
    "memberships": [
        {}
    ],
    "name": "Name of task",
    "parent": {
        "gid": "1201400250397199",
        "name": "name of parent task"
    },
    "permalink_url": "https://url...."
}
```

If you don't want unicode characters to be escaped, add the argument `ensure_ascii=False`:

```
print(json.dumps(task, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```