# SIMPLE Pythonic way to Pretty Print requests.response Headers

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to pretty print the http response coming back from Python Requests library in a fully Pythonic way without using any packages not built into the Python Standard Library.  I am getting the JSON run around.

**What I tried:**

I tried loading the response.headers into a JSON string using json.loads(), and then indenting the output using json.dumps(), as follows,

```
import json
response_json = json.loads(response.headers)

pretty_response = json.dumps(response_json, indent=4)
print(pretty_response)
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 2
      1 import json
----> 2 response_json = json.loads(response.headers)
      4 pretty_response = json.dumps(response_json, indent=4)
      5 print(pretty_response)

File c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\webscrapers\lib\json\__init__.py:341, in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    339 else:
    340     if not isinstance(s, (bytes, bytearray)):
--> 341         raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
    342                         f'not {s.__class__.__name__}')
    343     s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
    345 if "encoding" in kw:

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not CaseInsensitiveDict
```

**I also tried:**

First installing and importing the `rich` package, and then using a module within the `rich` package for Rich Text Formatting output to terminals. The print_json() function is supposed to pretty print json:

```
import json
import rich
rich.print_json(dict(response.headers))
```

but I get an error:

```
TypeError: json must be str. Did you mean print_json(data={'Date': 'Sun, 18 Jun 2023 16:22:08 GMT', ...}
```

I finally got it to work by installing and importing the `rich` package and using some hints from [How to pretty print nested dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229419/how-to-pretty-print-nested-dictionaries) and [Requests: Pretty print http response headers](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/requests-pretty-print-http-response-headers/567548).

```
import rich
rich.pretty.pprint(dict(response.headers))
```

However, it took some time to figure out the correct syntax, because the rich.pretty.pprint `help()` documentation in Jupyter did not have detailed examples for this use case.  While `rich` is a very nice package, it has a significant learning curve.  More importantly, it is not a native Python built-in solution.

How can this be done simply using Python with no 3rd party package installations?

Comment: Have you tried using https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html?

Answer (score 2):

```py
from pprint import pprint

pprint(dict(response.headers))
```

Comment: Thank you!   I finally got it to work using the exact code you posted.  This displays the indented text as plain text in Jupyter NB.   I am wondering if there is a way to have colored text output using built-in Python?

Comment: U can use "colorama"
```python
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

# Print colored text
print(f"{Fore.RED}This is red text.")
print(f"{Back.GREEN}This has a green background.")
print(f"{Style.BRIGHT}This is bright text.")
print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}{Back.BLUE}You can combine colors.{Style.RESET_ALL}")

# Reset colors to default
print(f"{Style.RESET_ALL}This is back to normal.")
```
U can use it with pprint if u whant
```python
print(f"{Fore.RED}{pformat(dict(response.headers))}{Style.RESET_ALL}")
```